# Any Experiments that verify the assumption of identical particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, identical-particles

I am wondering why the bosons and fermions' behaviors are weird.
Here is the statement on Wikipedia of the [statistical properties of bosons and fermions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles#Statistical_properties_of_bosons_and_fermions)

> If A and B are distinguishable particles, then the composite system has four distinct states: |0>|0>,|0>|1>,|1>|1>, |1>|0>. The probability of obtaining two particles in the |0>|0> state is 0.25; the probability of obtaining two particles in the |1>|1> state is 0.25, and the probability of obtaining one particle in the |0> state and the other in the |1> state is 0.5.
> If A and B are identical bosons, then the composite system has only three distinct states: |0>|0>,|1>|1>, and $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0>|1>+|1>|>)$. When the experiment is performed, the probability of obtaining two particles in the |0>|0> state is now 0.33; the probability of obtaining two particles in the |1>|1> state is 0.33; and the probability of obtaining one particle in the |1> state and the other in the |0> state is 0.33. Note that the probability of finding particles in the same state is relatively larger than in the distinguishable case. This demonstrates the tendency of bosons to "clump."
> If A and B are identical fermions, there is only one state available to the composite system: the totally antisymmetric state $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0>|1>-|1>|>)$. When the experiment is performed, one particle is always in the |0> state and the other is in the |1> state.

My questions are:

1. Is there any experiment that could verify the above conclusions? I mean, in a real experiment, we could measure the probabilities in different states directly.
2. Based on the above assumptions, for Bosons, when there are 2 possible states for a single particle, there are only 3 possible states for a two-particle system. Could this be explained by other principles? Or this is just the result of experiments?
3. Electrons are fermions, assuming I have a piece of solid crystal, apparently, I could distinguish the atoms in different locations in the crystal structures, so I could distinguish the electron belonged to different atoms. Is that violating the principle of identical particles? And could I make the same deduction for the valence electrons
4. If the wave functions of two electrons are overlapped partially, are they still identical particles? If so, does it means whenever the wave functions of two fermions or bosons are overlapped, they could be treated as identical particles?

Comment: Stability of matter could be considered as experimental evidence for exchange, since it is largely dueto exchange interaction/forces. Regarding 4: when we have more than one particle, we describe them by a *joint* wave function. Overlap of wave functions is an approximation.